# Is Mark Manson's meta-feeling table based on any theory?

Tags: emotion, terminology, metacognition

Mark Manson from the article [Fuck Your Feelings](https://markmanson.net/fuck-your-feelings) introduces this table of what he calls "meta-feelings":

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| **Feeling Bad About Feeling Bad (Self-Loathing)** - Excessive self-criticism - Anxious/Neurotic behavior - Suppression of emotions - Engage in a lot of fake niceness/politeness - Feeling as though something is wrong with you | **Feeling Bad About Feeling Good (Guilt)** - Chronic guilt and feeling as though you [don’t deserve happiness](https://markmanson.net/how-to-be-happy) - Constant comparison of yourself to others - Feeling as though something *should* be wrong, even if everything is great - Unnecessary criticism and negativity |
| **Feeling Good About Feeling Bad (Self-Righteousness)** - Moral indignation - Condescension towards others - Feeling as though you deserve something others don’t - Seeking out a constant sense of powerlessness and victimization | **Feeling Good About Feeling Good (Ego/Narcissism)** - Self-congratulatory - Chronically overestimate yourself; a delusionally-positive self-perception - Unable to handle failure or rejection - Avoids confrontation or discomfort - Constant state of self-absorption |

Is this chart based on any theory? At first it seems like to be the same with [meta-emotion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-emotion), but reading that I feel like meta-emotion is more about parenting style, and focusing more on feeling bad about feelings (the top quadrants).

Here are the [four types](https://advice.theshineapp.com/articles/how-to-deal-with-your-meta-emotions-aka-feeling-bad-about-your-feelings/) of meta-emotions ([Bailen et al. 2019](https://doi.org/10.1037/emo0000488)):

> Meta-emotions can be classified into four types: negative-negative (e.g., feeling embarrassed about feeling sad), negative-positive (e.g., feeling guilty about feeling happy), **positive-positive (e.g., feeling hopeful about feeling relieved), and positive-negative (e.g., feeling pleased about feeling angry)**

The positive-negative and positive-positive emotions in meta-emotion doesn't seem to match with the bottom row of the table (self-righteousness and ego/narcissism). The chart also reminds me more about [moral emotions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_emotions).

### References

Bailen, N. H., Wu, H., & Thompson, R. J. (2019). Meta-emotions in daily life: Associations with emotional awareness and depression. *Emotion, 19*(5), 776–787. https://doi.org/10.1037/emo0000488

Comment: I haven't read the articles yet, but why do you say that the *positive-negative* and *positive-positive* emotions do not match the bottom row of the table?  *feeling hopeful about feeling relieved* and *feeling pleased about feeling angry* are only examples.  Looking at the table though, I would question some of the entries made by Mark Manson.  For example *Feeling as though you deserve something others don’t* when you are feeling a negative-negative emotion?

Comment: I also haven't read Bailen et al due to paywall; the quote from [this article](https://advice.theshineapp.com/articles/how-to-deal-with-your-meta-emotions-aka-feeling-bad-about-your-feelings/) is the only one I have. The positive-positive and positive-negative quadrants in meta-emotion theory seem to be healthy mental states, while the counterparts quadrants in Mark Manson's chart are not that healthy. "Feeling as though you deserve something others don’t" is a positive-negative emotion, not a negative-negative emotion